# How to unmount a portal?

Tags: reactjs, react-portal

I need to port some legacy (React 16) code to a fresh (React 18) project. I'm stuck at the `ReactDOM` render/unmount, which are no longer supported.

Here is an example of code where the problem occurs:

```
import { createRoot, Root } from "react-dom/client";

export type TDialogHostShowResult<TResult> = {
    canceled: boolean;
    result?: TResult;
}

export type TDialogHostResult<TResult> = {
    show: () => Promise<TDialogHostShowResult<TResult>>;
}

export type TDialogHostContext<TResult> = {
    resolve: (result: TResult) => void;
    close: () => void;
}

export type TDialogHostProps<TResult> = {
    onGetContent: (ctx: TDialogHostContext<TResult>) => JSX.Element;
}

export function dialogHost<TResult>(
    props: TDialogHostProps<TResult>
): TDialogHostResult<TResult> {

    const {
        onGetContent,
    } = props;

    const show = (): Promise<TDialogHostShowResult<TResult>> => {

        return new Promise<TDialogHostShowResult<TResult>>(
            resolve => {
                let root: Root | null;
                let div: HTMLDivElement | null = document.createElement('div');
                document.body.appendChild(div);

                const cleanup = (): void => {
                    if (root) {
                        root.unmount();                   // <-- NEW CODE
                        root = null;
                    }
                    //ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);  <-- OLD CODE
                    if (div) {
                        document.body.removeChild(div);
                        div = null;
                    }
                }

                const ctx: TDialogHostContext<TResult> = {
                    resolve: result => {
                        cleanup();
                        resolve({
                            canceled: false,
                            result,
                        })
                    },
                    close: () => {
                        cleanup();
                        resolve({
                            canceled: true,
                        })
                    },
                };

                try {
                    //content rendering
                    const content = onGetContent(ctx);
                    root = createRoot(div);            // <-- NEW CODE
                    root.render(content);              // <-- NEW CODE
                    //ReactDOM.render(content, div);      <-- OLD CODE
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                    cleanup();
                }
            }
        );
    };

    return {
        show,
    }
}
```

The above function gets called in this way (`DialogAlert` omitted):

```
export async function showDialogAlert(props: ShowDialogAlertProps): Promise<void> {
    const dlgHost = dialogHost<void>({
        onGetContent: ctx => (
            <DialogAlert
                {...props}
                onClose={() => ctx.close()}
            />
        )
    });

    await dlgHost.show();
}
```

That's a very convenient way to surrogate the classic `alert` method, just to clarify the reasons of all that.

Everything works fine (at least, it seems to me).

That being said, the latest React's docs say that `createRoot` should not used for rendering parts and `createPortal` should be used instead ([see here](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot#caveats)).

> When you want to render a piece of JSX in a different part of the DOM
> tree that isn’t a child of your component (for example, a modal or a
> tooltip), use createPortal instead of createRoot.

However, I couldn't find a way to "unmount" a portal unless it's place as part of a JSX fragment.

So, the questions are:

1. is it safe anyway using `createRoot` in situations like the above one?
2. alternatively, is there a React supported mechanism to use
   `createPortal`, then safely unmount it?